# How do I add format specifiers to NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps, nsurl

I have the following code that makes a Google Places API request. The parameters are statically set at the moment. How would I go about making those parameters (types and lat/lon and the Google Key - which I've defined as a constant in the .h file) objects instead?

My problem arises with the NSURL because I can't add format specifiers to it.

thanks for any help.

```
-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI
{

    NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=bar&sensor=false&key=MyGoogleAPIKey"];

    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
    xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *arr = [xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"result"];

    for(GDataXMLElement *e in arr )
    {
        [placesOutputArray addObject:e];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful for you

```
float lat=34.0522222,lon=-118.2427778;
NSString *typestr=@"bar";
NSString *key=@"MyGoogleAPIKey";


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&types=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",lat,lon,typestr,key]];

NSLog(@"url values  ==%@",url);
```

Answer (score 4):

Good ol' [`stringWithFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)?

```
`NSString* urlToCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:://url.to.webservice/api?param1=%@&param2=%@", param1, param2]`
```

Answer (score 1):

Format specifiers directly to NSURL like this:

```
 NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:://url.to.webservice/api?param1=%@%param2=%@", param1, param2]];
```